# Concisely mapping 2 columns from 2D array to key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

In this example snippet of code, I selectively convert 2 columns from my 2D array into an object. The 1st column represents the keys, the 2nd represents the values.

I feel like there is a more concise way of codifying this idea without so many lines of code.

```
var my2dArray = [ ['a',2], ['b',3], ['c',4] ];
var keys = [];
var values = [];
var myObj = {};

for(var row = 1; row < my2dArray.length; row++) {
    keys[row] = my2dArray[row][0];
    values[row] = my2dArray[row][1];
    myObj[keys[row]] = values[row];
}

console.log(prod_compare); // outputs object
```

In reality, I have a 4 column array. Don't mind the simplicity of `my2dArray`. Is there a way to select these two columns for mapping to an object without having to declare 2 temporary arrays?

Comment: I sincerely can't see the use of `keys` and `values` in your code...also, array index starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: I convert the 2 relevant columns into their own 1D arrays. As for the initialization in the for loop, I intentionally did that.

Comment: Yes, but you said those two arrays are temporary, which, I assume you don't need that afterward. If it's correct, I don't see why you can't directly use `myObj[my2dArray[row][0]]=my2dArray[row][1];`.

Comment: If that was an answer, I would've given you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally OK, but it can be more concise without being obfuscated:

```
var my2dArray = [ ['a',2], ['b',3], ['c',4] ];
var myObj = {};

for (var i=0, iLen=my2dArray.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  myObj[my2dArray[i][0]] = my2dArray[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Not sure what purpose `iLen` serves but this works great! Thank you!!

Comment: It is a minor optimisation so that *my2dArray.length* is not accessed on every loop. Probably makes zero difference in modern browsers, it's mostly habbit I guess.

Comment: That makes total sense. I will do that from now on! Every iota counts.

Answer (score 0):

This may convert `[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 1, 2, 3]]` to `{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [1, 2, 3]}`.

```
for(var row = 0; row < my2dArray.length; row++) {
    keys[row] = my2dArray[row][0];
    values[row] = my2dArray[row].slice(1);
    myObj[keys[row]] = values[row];
}
```